# Rotativa - ViewAspdf does not work on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation, rotativa

I know that this topic has been discuss on several articles, but none of the solution help me.

I have this action:

```
   public ActionResult DownloadViewPDF(string userId)
        {
            var model = db.MyCvs.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);

            if (model != null)
                return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("ViewUserCv", model) { FileName = model.FirstName + model.LastName + "_CV.pdf" };
            return Content("there is no Cv to download");
        }
```

Using the above action I am downloading a view as pdf, and everything is working as expected on my computer.

After deploying the project on the server, this action is not working, is returning an error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web  request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be  identified using the exception stack trace
>   below.

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015. 
On the server I have the `Rotativa.dll` and also the Folder in the root directory named Rotativa with the file inside named `wkhtmltopdf.exe`.

I do not know how to handle this error, can you give me some sugestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a very simple tutorial how to fix my issue with rotativa, for those which have the same issue, please follow this tutorial:

[Sample process to generate PDF with Rotativa in Asp.Net MVC](http://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a1702/sample-process-to-generate-pdf-with-rotativa-in-asp_net-mvc.aspx)

based on this tutorial, all we need to do is to:

Upload dlls:

- msvcp120.dll
- msvcr120.dll

because Rotativa need component of "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio".

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio  12.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\X64\msvcp120.dll
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio  12.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\X64\msvcr120.dll
>
> You can refer above path on your local with your own specified path to
>   find it.  Upload them to "Rotativa" folder.

Comment: I found the missing dll in "C:\Windows\System32" (Windows 7, x64)

Comment: This worked for me too. I added the two DLL's to the Rotatoria folder and there was no issue on the server.
 msvcp120.dll and msvcr120.dll

Comment: Link atrophy over time. Please include summary text/code from the link to ensure this answer stays relevant/accurate over time.

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was, I had files missing in the Rotativa folder,

```
help-wkhtmltoimage.txt
help-wkhtmltopdf.txt
msvcp120.dll
msvcp140.dll
msvcr120.dll
vcruntime140.dll
wkhtmltoimage.exe
wkhtmltopdf.exe
wkhtmltox.dll
```

Once I put those files in, it worked like a charm

Comment: This one didn't deserve a downvote: I needed to combine this with Lucian's answer to get it to work.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue: Rotativa was working for me on local, but not on our development server.

What worked for me was a combination of Lucian Bumb and Ray Levron's answers.

First I went to: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html and downloaded the 64-bit version.

I ran the installer, found the bin folder, and copied these three files into my project's "Rotativa" folder:

- wkhtmltoimage.exe
- wkhtmltopdf.exe
- wkhtmltox.dll

I then found these four .dll files on my PC running a search, and copied them into my project's "Rotativa" folder:

- msvcp120.dll
- msvcp140.dll
- msvcr120.dll
- vcruntime140.dll

Made sure all files were added to project and source control, tested local, and checked in for a build on dev.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It's a great help.

Comment: for rotativa version 1.7.4-rc, it is using version 0.12.4.0 of the ff files
wkhtmltoimage.exe
wkhtmltopdf.exe
wkhtmltox.dll
https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/tag/0.12.4

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue:

1. Open the C++ redistributable Package for Visual studio 2013 downloadable link below:
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=40784 Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013
2. Click Download and choose the file (vcredist_x86.exe) even if you are running X64 bit server version.
3. Install the file.

this will add the missing dll file mentioned above, and the problem is now solved.